# Initializing c++ arrays with references to variables and then values

Tags: c++11

I saw in some source code something like this

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM; i++){
   count[i] = new int;
   *count[i] = 0;
}
```

And was wondering what the point was as opposed to just having:

`count[i] = 0;`

Comment: One possible reason: the elements of the array in the first code block will persist even after the `count` array goes out of scope.  The elements of the array in the second code block will not be accessible after the array goes out of scope.

Comment: Okay, thanks.  So it could be that the count[x] sets a different variable so you want the value to still be there when count gets destroyed?

Comment: I may be looking at things too simply, but maybe `count` is just an array of `int*`?

Comment: The only thing with this code is that you would have a memory leak if you ever lost track of the pointer created with `count[i] = new int`.

Answer (score 1):

> And was wondering what the point was as opposed to just having `count[i] = 0;`

Well, initializing a pointer to zero has a different meaning than initializing the pointed value to zero.

Dereferencing a pointer that points to a valid object is OK, and returns the value of the object. Dereferencing a pointer with the value zero (i.e. a null pointer) has undefined behaviour.

---

You may instead be wondering, why would you want to use an array pointers to dynamically allocated integers, instead of an array of integers. You're right to question it, since it is quite rarely a rational choice. However, this snippet doesn't demonstrate any reason for doing so. If possible, you may find out by asking the person who wrote the code.